# Type Casting of pointers in C

Tags: c, casting

Im learning about typecasting in void pointers
and the part of *((typecasting) void_pointer) i am not undestanting why need this *( before the real type casting.

Can someone explain me this part of code:

```
printf("[int pointer] points to %p, which contains the int %d\n", void_pointer, *((int *) void_pointer));
```

what this part does`*((int *) void_pointer))`

(Sorry my english)

Comment: You need that to dereference the pointer, just like you would if you didn't need to cast it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that `void_pointer` is of type `void *`. Void pointers can point to any type, you can't dereference them directly. So let's break down `*((int *) void_pointer`. First, it is casted to an `int` pointer (this is what `(int *) void_pointer`) does. Then, the pointer is dereferenced in order to get the value it points to. You can rewrite it as:

```c
int *int_pointer = (int *) void_pointer;
int int_value = *int_pointer;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `void` pointer simply speaking contains raw address of *something*, but it doesn't know which data type *something* represents. That's why you cannot dereference it, because size and type of the resulting entity is unknown. To undergo such a limitation, you have to convert `void` pointer to non-`void` pointer(in your case it's `int*` which is on most systems is 4 bytes long) and after that you can easily dereference it and do arithmetic on it with no warnings generated by a compiler.